# efficient way to find set membership

Tags: performance, algorithm, set, time-complexity, bitstring

I am working with 2^n vector e.g. n=3 the possible values are:

000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111

I would like to find what is the most efficient way, given the set of combinations say

000, 000, 001, 100, 000, 110, 000, 110

how to find if a given value is in the possible set.

One way would be to go through the entire list (brute force).  Another would be to use any of the classic search methods e.g. binary search etc for log_2(n) +1

Another method would be to use Bloom filters, although this is a probabilistic method

I want to know if there's anything else out there, that given a list of bit strings, to efficiently test for its membership.

Comment: If n can be very large, you might be interested in this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_Boltzmann_machine

Comment: If all you need is membership checking, an efficient hash function and a hash set should do the trick.

Comment: There's also the vEB tree, possibly not space efficient though (depends on the data set)

Answer (score 0):

Any data structure will work.  I'd reach for whatever your local dictionary structure is because that is simple to do and is well-tested code.  Usually that is a hash, though it is often called something else like a dictionary, HashMap, or std::unordered_map.  Sometimes it is a binary tree. hash (Perl), dictionary (Python), HashMap.

If I was to roll a "perfect data structure for this problem" I'd probably want some variant on a trie.  But the maximum win from that is a fairly small factor speedup, so why bother unless I know that it is needed?

Answer (score 0):

A hash-based set of some kind (a `HashSet` in Java, for instance) will do insertions and lookups in amortized constant time, which is the best you're going to get in asymptotic terms.

If you really want to push the boat out, and the set will be dense (i.e., a decent proportion of the possible bit strings are expected to be present), then convert them to integers and use a bitfield. This is also constant time, but a faster constant.